# Importing multiple React Components

Tags: reactjs, components

I'm a beginner in React so looking for some direction here.

I have created two components files and am trying to import them under App.js. But it's not yielding the desired result. Only one component (HeaderSection) with Navbar and header details is getting displayed. Other (eventOptions) component has two buttons in it that i wanna display under navbar. that's not getting displayed.

How do i get eventoptions displayed as child component ? It's working in one of my other projects but not in this even though i have imported all the files.

```js
import logo from './logo.svg'; 
import './App.css'; 
import HeaderSection from './component/HeaderSection'; 
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'; 
import eventOptions from './component/eventOptions'; 
import { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component{   render(){
    return(
      <div className="App">
        <HeaderSection />
        <eventOptions />

      </div>
    );

  } }

export default App;
```

//////////////////////////
Updated code:

EventOptions component :

> import React, { Component } from 'react'
>
> class eventOptions extends Component {
>
> ```
> render() {
>     
>     const {event, flag} = this.props; 
>     
>     return (
>         <div >
>             {flag?(<h2>{event.EventName}</h2>): null}
>          
>         </div>
>     )
> } } export default eventOptions;
> ```

EventsState component:

> import React, { Component } from 'react' import EventOptions from
> './EventOptions'
>
> class EventsState extends Component {
> state={
>
> ```
>     flag: false,
>     title: "State Check",
>     events : [
>           {
>               EventId: '1',
>               EventName: 'New Year Party 2022',
>               Venue: 'The Social',
>               Time: '8:00 PM- 1:00AM'
>           },
>           {
>             EventId: '2',
>             EventName: 'StandUp Comedy',
>             Venue: 'ShilpaRamam',
>             Time: '8:00 PM- 1:00AM'
>         },
>         {
>             EventId: '3',
>             EventName: 'Live Music',
>             Venue: '10 Downing Street',
>             Time: '8:00 PM- 1:00AM'
>         },
>         {
>             EventId: '4',
>             EventName: 'Karakoe Night',
>             Venue: 'The Rooftop lounge',
>             Time: '8:00 PM- 1:00AM'
>         }
>     ]
> }
>    test = ()=>{console.log("clicked")};
>
> render() {
>   
>     const {events} = this.state;
>     return (
>         
>         <div class= "container">
>               <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" >Add Event</button>
>             <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" >Search Event</button>
>             <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onClick={()=>{this.setState= !this.state.flag}}>Show All
> ```
>
> Events
>
> {events.map(event =>
>
> )}
>
> ```
>          </div>
>     )
> } }
> ```
>
> export default EventsState;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're rendering the component in smaller case.

You need to do it like so

```
import EventOptions from './component/eventOptions';

class App extends Component{   
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="App">
          <HeaderSection />
          <EventOptions />
        </div>
      );
  }
}
```

If you start a component name with a lowercase letter, it will be treated like a built-in element like a `<div>` or a `<span>` . This is because of the way JSX works. In JSX, rendering a component that begins with a lowercase letter compiles down to `React.createElement('component')`, the equivalent of an HTML element

Update:

```
// Please return from your map callback
{events.map(currentEvent => {
  return (
    <h1>{currentEvent.EventName}</h1>
  );
}

// Or you can do this for short
{events.map(currentEvent => (<h1>{currentEvent.EventName}</h1>)}
```

Comment: I had one ,more question. So i'm rendering the   below  class also in app.js.  But the  clickme()  method is not working , any idea ? Please find the code below in comment section and let me know. After clicking on the third button, i don't see anything console. Also, state components are not getting rendered.

Comment: Your state components are not getting loaded as you're not returning from your map function. You need to return `return <h1>{currentEvent.EventName}</h1>`. As for your click event everything seems fine. You may add it to a codesandbox and update it here. Also its always a good practice to name your methods in camelCase, i.e., `clickMe`

Comment: Can you tell me whats wrong with my if condition inside map method ? I'm still getting the values in console but not on the UI. Without if, I'm able to get the details on UI. Adding the code below in the chain.

Comment: Where is your if condition? Can you edit your question and add the code?

Comment: My post got hidden by someone for some reason. I'm posting it again.

Comment: That's because you're adding it as an answer. Please edit the question and add there.

Comment: Added update to answer. Please remove your answer as its not a an answer to the above question.

Comment: Please check the question section now, have updated both compents. I want to display the contents depending on the flag status (which i'm changing by onclick from the button and passing the same flag value as props). then in eventoptions i'm just trying to render data depending on the flag value, this is not working :((((

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class EventsState extends Component {

state={
    flag : false, 
    title: "State Check",
    events : [
          {
              EventId: '1',
              EventName: 'New Year Party 2022',
              Venue: 'The Social',
              Time: '8:00 PM- 1:00AM'
          },
          {
            EventId: '2',
            EventName: 'StandUp Comedy',
            Venue: 'ShilpaRamam',
            Time: '8:00 PM- 1:00AM'
        },
        {
            EventId: '3',
            EventName: 'Live Music',
            Venue: '10 Downing Street',
            Time: '8:00 PM- 1:00AM'
        },
        {
            EventId: '4',
            EventName: 'Karakoe Night',
            Venue: 'The Rooftop lounge',
            Time: '8:00 PM- 1:00AM'
        }
    ]
}
    clickMe= () =>{
        this.setState({flag: !this.state.flag});
        if(this.state.flag==true){
        console.log("Clicked me!");
      const {events} = this.state;
}
render() {
    const {events} = this.state;
   
    return (
        
        <div>
        <h2>
            {this.state.title}
        </h2>
        {events.map(currentEvent =>{
            <h1>{currentEvent.EventName}</h1>
        })}
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" >Add Event</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" >Search Event</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onClick={this.ClickMe} >Show All Events</button>
             
             
        </div>
    )
} } export default EventsState;
```